# Why do I get a 403 error when accessing my apache server?

Tags: 12.04, apache2

Im running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a system with 2 GB RAM and a 500 GB HDD.

My hard drive has 4 partitions:

- Partition 1 = 40 gb Windows (NTFS, lable = win32)
- Partition 2 = 320 gb Windows (FAT label = common)
- Partition 3 = 40 gb Ubuntu (EXT4)

I installed `apached2`. Then, to change its default `www` directory, I ran `gksu gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and, in the editor, changed the location to `/media/common/www`.

After that I ran these commands in a terminal:

```
chmod 777 /media/common/www 
chmod 777 /media/common/www/*.*
```

After that I ran: `firefox 127.0.0.1/index.php`

It said:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

Before my changes it was working fine.

How can I run my websites?

Comment: It seems I have jeopardized myself by the my short knowledge, and community being unable to help as 16 hours are more than enough for experts like you, even google results are not helping me. WHAT NEXT ...

Comment: Not all questions are answered the day they are posted. You can check out [other Ubuntu help resources](http://www.ubuntu.com/support), but whether or not you decide to use some of those resources now, I counsel patience. Most of us "experts" have lives outside of Ask Ubuntu, school/jobs, and other commitments. We're volunteers who may or may not be able to respond quickly to assist you or anyone else (and you'll find that's the case for the other free support resources too). If that doesn't work for you, you might consider [buying support](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/overview).

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Does `index.php` exists in that location? Or does not not exist, and you're hoping to see a virtual directory listing?

Comment: To be or not to be, that is the question....

Comment: @nishan Please consider accepting an answer, if your problem is solved by any one of them. This will help future visitors. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I guess that, Your `common` partition may be an `ntfs` or `fat` partition and You just mounted that partition by clicking on the nautilus side bar icon. Doing so, does not mount the partition with `executable` permission, which is required for firefox to be able to execute the file.

#### The solution:

The easiest solution without using `/etc/fstab` file is this:

- Open a terminal and type `sudo blkid`, give password.
- From the output of the command, see the type of the partition by looking at the corresponding label, i.e `common`.
- If `common` partition happen to be `/dev/sda2` , mount that partition with the command:

  ```
    udisks --mount /dev/sda2 --mount-options umask=022
  ```

  replace, `/dev/sda2` with the actual partition number.

You should now be able to execute/run the files using "Firefox".

**Note:** You should unmount the partition before using the command. You can unmount it by right-clicking on the partition icon, and select "unmount" from the options

Comment: I have faced this problem and tested this method, which works. So, I wrote the solution. It is not necessary for you to agree with me.

Comment: @neon_overload, I suggest you to setup a web server with document root at a folder in ntfs partition. then mount the partition with nautilus, which mounts without `exec` permission. Then put some `.php` file in it, then try access to these files with Firefox. Then let me know what happened. Please, don't overload me with comments without actually you verified that this is not a real solution. I hope you will try this.

Comment: I have tested this today. It is working exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what i can tell, chmod won't work on directories the way you use it- you really should try `chmod -R 777 /path/to/main/directory/` to make it recursive. Then again, You don't want 777 for most things - but the exact permissions level would depend on your setup - I just hand over ownership to www-data and run things with 755 - which dosen't let non owners write, but gives full read/execute powers.

Amusingly the error messages should have given most of this away. For a better writeup on how to set permissions, see this question on [webmasters.se](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/when-creating-a-website-what-permissions-and-directory-structure)

Comment: I covered that *and* better permissions settings in my answer - the executable bit is for scripts to run - which as i recall, are run *by* www-data. 755 is what *many* scripts recommend, and came to mind. "the exact permissions level would depend on your setup" is a VERY important point here.

Comment: Lets look at the *bigger* picture here - is he running static sites? He is running a php script, and that would indicate, no, he is running dynamic content through a PHP script. How do PHP scripts run? They need to be executed. What user executes files from PHP? I'm guessing www-data. The top voted answer to the question i referenced agree. You don't. *citation needed* http://xkcd.com/285/ .

Comment: @neon_overload - if it's such a bad idea, i would think it wouldn't also be a component of your answer...