# How can I serve files via apache2 from an internal ntfs partition using fstab ntfs-3g?

Tags: permissions, apache2, ntfs, fstab

I have apache2 setup and serving files successfully from locations such as:

`/var/www/example.com`

where ownership and permissions were set like this:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com`

`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

resulting permissions look like:

`drwxr-xr-x 6 tim tim 4096 Aug 23 23:22 example.com/`

`drwxr-xr-x 5 tim tim 4096 Aug 24 14:45 www/`

and apache2.conf includes:

`ServerName 127.0.0.1`

and hosts includes

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

a browser successfully loads:

`localhost/example.com`

---

### the above is all good but...

I get 403s when I attempt to setup files to be served from an ntfs partition with:

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

`/dev/sda3 /media/tim/Data  ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_GB.utf8    0   2`

`sudo umount /media/tim/Data`

`sudo mount -a`

and use the same chown and chmod method above:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/tim/Data/www/example.com`

`sudo chmod -R 755 /media/tim/Data/www`

with a symbolic link such as:

`/var/www/ $ ln -s /media/tim/Data/www/example.com`

The symbolic link works with these permissions:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 tim tim 36 Aug 24 14:45 example.com -> /media/tim/Data/www/example.com`

and the permissions for the folders look like this:

`drwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim 8192 Aug 24 15:16 /media/tim/Data/www/example.com`

`drwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim 0 Aug 23 23:24 /media/tim/Data/www/`

---

### i have also tried

setting up virtualhost successfully on the local ext4 file system, but again got 403s if the virtualhost pointed to `/media/tim/Data/www/example.com` or the symbolic link `/var/www/example.com`

I've seen others apparently solve the issue with the fstab method, and as far as I can tell my permissions are also set correctly this way, but still fails.

Answers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/163693/187012)

I saw many apparently found a way to use `/media/` as the method of mounting and pointing to, but I was not able to do this successfully with my internal ntfs partition.

The solution was to mount the ntfs partition to a subdirectory of `/mnt/` and give that sub directory the necessary permissions.

```
cd /mnt
sudo mkdir Data
sudo chown tim:tim Data
sudo chmod 755 Data
```

then

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab` adding the line:

`/dev/sda3 /mnt/Data ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=tim,gid=tim,utf8,dmask=002,fmask=113 0 0`

and

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` with:

`DocumentRoot /mnt/Data/www`

and

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` with:

`DocumentRoot /mnt/Data/www/example.com`

Using this method apache2 can now serve a site from an ntfs partition.