# How to allow other users to access a mounted NTFS partition with a UserMapping file?

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I can't get users other than me or root to access the files on a mounted NTFS partition. The answers I've found to similar questions usually mention to set the uid and gid options. In my situation I mount the partition with ntfs-3g and have a UserMapping file defined in the default location. As mentioned in the manual this causes the uid and gid settings to be ignored.

Everything works fine when I access the partition normally. I'm able to change permissions, ownership and execute files, so that's great. However, it would be nice if apache (running as www-data) can also access the files on the partition, which it can't right now.

The line in fstab looks like this:

```
<UUID> <mount point> ntfs-3g x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data,exec,hide_hid_files,hide_dot_files 0 0
```

To test the access for the apache user I've simply tried:

```
sudo -u www-data ls -all <absolute path to mount point>
```

Which returns:

```
ls: cannot access Data: Permission denied
```

I also tried to change the group on the mount point to the same group the www-data user is in (which is www-data), without effect.

Is there anything I overlook or can try? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

Output of ntfs-3g.secaudit Data/Server/index.html

```
secaudit 1.4.0 : NTFS security data auditing
File Data/Server/index.html
Windows attrib : 0x20
Interpreted Unix owner 1000, group 33, mode 0666
No errors were found
```

Output of ntfs-3g.secaudit Data/Server/

```
secaudit 1.4.0 : NTFS security data auditing
Directory Data/Server/
Windows attrib : 0x30
Interpreted Unix owner 1000, group 33, mode 0750
Posix descriptor :
    acccnt 3
    defcnt 3
    firstdef 3
    mode : 0750
    tagsset : 0x25
Posix ACL :
    version 2
    flags 0x00
ace 0 : access  USR-O   -1 perms 0007 rwx
ace 1 : access  GRP-O   -1 perms 0005 r-x
ace 2 : access  OTHER   -1 perms 0000 ---
ace 3 : default USR-O   -1 perms 0007 rwx
ace 4 : default GRP-O   -1 perms 0007 rwx
ace 5 : default OTHER   -1 perms 0007 rwx
No errors were found
```

Comment: Using `ln` to test for file access is rather strange to me. Why not use `sudo -u www-data cat somefile` or even `ls`  or `touch`

Comment: Sorry, that should've been ls instead of ln! Changed it immediately. The Permission denied error remains however, also when I try cat or touch.

Comment: what is the output of `ntfs-3g.secaudit yourfileonntfspartition` ?

Comment: I added the output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336852/how-can-i-serve-files-via-apache2-from-an-internal-ntfs-partition-using-fstab-nt), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163685/403-forbidden-error-in-apache-with-document-root-on-an-ntfs-partition/163693#163693) and [here](http://www.tbogard.com/2014/09/12/making-apache-server-to-read-a-partitioned-disk-the-definitive-solution/).

Whant went wrong is that I added my mount point to the /media instead of the /mnt directory (as explained in the first and second link). So the permission issue is fixed with:

```
<UUID> /mnt/Data ntfs-3g x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data,exec,hide_hid_files,hide_dot_files 0 0
```

instead of:

```
<UUID> /media/kevin/Data ntfs-3g x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data,exec,hide_hid_files,hide_dot_files 0 0
```

That effectively answers my question.

To be sure that apache would really load the page instead of returning a 403 forbidden response, only one thing remained to be done. The apache configuration needed to have the following Directory settings (as explained in the third link). I added this to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

```
<Directory "/mnt/Data/www">
   allow from all
   Options +Indexes
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

That's it! Apache can now serve my site from the ntfs partition.